# Bulk restore revision on all posts on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a wordpress plugin to restore revisions on multiple posts at once based on date or position?

I have a hacked site in which every post was changed. To make all content clean I would need to restore all posts to a wherever revision was online 5 or 6 days ago.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Revision is provided by wordpress. You can restore the content by checking each post.

Comment: I am aware. However, since I need to restore multiple revisions at once, I am asking if there is a way to do it in bulk, instead of individually post by post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, with a hacked site - your best bet is to restore a Database/MySQL backup from a time when it was "clean", or just reverting them manually.

That said, WordPress does let you retrieve revisions using [`wp_get_post_revisions()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_revisions/).

> **NOTE**: This is the *plural* function, the singular function [`wp_get_post_revision()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_revision/) get a revision by its ID. Unless you know what the ID of the revision you want is, you don't want this function.The plural function gets all revisions of a post.

Now, before you continue reading - BACK UP YOUR SITE.

Did you back it up?

Make sure you HAVE A BACKUP.

Also, make sure it's a backup that works.

Now, that you *have a backup*...

Take a look at this function that I came up with, it uses `wp_get_post_revisions()` in conjunction with [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/). Again, PLEASE make sure you back up before running this function. It's going to mess with posts and post content, and if it stalls/dies, it could get messy. **Use at your own risk**.

- First, it makes sure you WANT to run this function by visiting `https://yoursite.com/?restore_revisions=so_50959583_restore_revisions`. It needs that query string to run.
- Then it makes sure the current user has admin level privileges.
- Then it checks to see if this function has run before, so it doesn't run every time.
- Now it runs a standard [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to grab all `posts`. Note I've ommitted other post types, you can add those in if you want.
- Inside the loop, it checks to see if a revision exists, and if so it uses `wp_update_post` to update the post to the revised `post_content`.
- If it fails here, it will die with a message to prevent setting the flag we checked in the beginning.
- Provided it runs smoothly, it sets the `so_50959583_restore_revisions_flag` option flag so it won't ever run again.
- At this point, you should remove the code.
- **NOTE** you could remove the option flag, and set this up as a custom plugin and run the function off of [`register_activation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook).

So, here's the beast, best used for *illustrative purposes*, use it at your own risk.

```
add_action( 'init', 'so_50959583_restore_revisions' );
function so_50959583_restore_revisions(){
    if( isset( $_GET['restore_revisions'] ) && $_GET['restore_revisions'] == 'so_50959583_restore_revisions' ){
        if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){
            if( !get_option( 'so_50959583_restore_revisions_flag' ) ){
                // This hasn't run before, run it now.
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post', // Limit to just posts
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                );

                $revision_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if( $revision_query->have_posts() ){
                    while( $revision_query->have_posts() ){
                        $revision_query->the_post();

                        if( $last_revision = array_shift( wp_get_post_revisions( $post->ID ) ) ){
                            // At least one revision existed.
                            $reverted_post = array(
                                'ID' => get_the_ID(), // Update current post in query
                                'post_content' => $last_revision->post_content // set content to previous content
                            );

                            // Update the existing post
                            if( !wp_update_post( $reverted_post ) ){
                                wp_die( 'Something went wrong' );
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }

                // Whew, completed!
                update_option( 'so_50959583_restore_revisions_flag', true );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> I would like to stress, again, that your best bet is to keep backups of your database using one of the many available (and ofttimes FREE) plugins, to prevent issues like this from occurring.

Last, if you only have like 20-30 posts, you should just do it by hand. And if you have like 10,000 posts you may need to have this code do it in "chunks" or it may timeout.

Best of luck

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks!